# Can't run script at startup

Tags: debian, startup, init-script

Debian Buster

Xfce cant use <kbd>Super</kbd> (system symbol key) to open `wishkermenu` emulating the windows behavior of startmenu.

So I installed `xcape`,  to modify keys, and ran the shell command

```
xcape -e 'Super_L=Control_L|Escape'
```

(I use the key to other things so I use that `xcape` to when release the key, it emulates <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, I configure in keyboard hotkeys of `xfce` and assign <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to `wishkermenu`)

Works fine, the problem is that when I close the session I must run the command again. I tried to make a script and run it at startup following examples on the web but nothing happens. The script works correctly when I run it from shell, so the fail its on the startup ambit.

Used `crontab` and `etc/init.d` but nothing happens. Heard that on debian its not good use different methods than systemd for that.

How can I solve this problem, maybe a service?

Comment: You might want to tell us how you're trying to run the script at startup, not just "by following examples". Edit your question to include this.

Comment: I used cron and etc/init.d but nothing hsppends

Comment: cron/init.d probably run before your desktop is loaded, so it does not do anything. Add your script to "Startup Applications", maybe you even need to add a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, just writed a barch script and executed it on startup applications Xfce4 menu.
Thx 4 freedback

Answer (score 0):

Add your line with a command into `~/profile` or `~/xprofile` file. Depends on how is your system configured. You can try both.

These files should be loaded after your session is started, so the script will be automatically executed.